# Delete (wrong) remote branch an push (right) branch when two branches have the same name

Tags: git

I accidentaly checked out a branch from my currently checked out branch, kept working and commiting to this branch, let's call this branch `feature/foo`.

Then I realized I'm on the wrong branch and since there were only a few changes I reseted hard to the right branch and added again the changes and deleted the other branch with `git branch -d foo`. Everything looked fine in gitk.

Now i try to push and get:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://some-repository.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Now a `git fetch` brings back the deleted branch. Now I'm stuck with `feature/foo`, which contains the changes and `remotes/origin/feature/foo`, which i want to remove.

How can i get rid of the `remotes/origin/feature/foo` and be able to push my changes?

Comment: what is git pull saying.

Comment: * [new branch]        feature/foo -> origin/feature/foo
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> feature/foo

Comment: git push origin <currentbranchname>

Comment: Unfortunately not, `git push origin feature/foo` gives me the above message (`error: failed to push some refs...`) when it is the current checked out branch.

Comment: try 
first git checkout master, then
git pull

Comment: I can checkout master, but how does this help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717975/totally-stuck-in-git-git-push-does-not-work-and-git-pull-doesnt-fix

Comment: Nope still can't push `fatal: The current branch feature/foo has no upstream branch.`

Comment: push using git push origin <currentbranchname>

Comment: I did. `git push origin feature/...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the two branches had the same name. Renaming the currently checked out branch fixed this.